# Flutter - The getter 'message' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an error with messages, i have seen everyone using it for displaying errors, but I just get an error : The getter 'message' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

```
Future<String> logInUserWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
String retVal = 'error';
//code

  retVal = 'success';
} catch (e) {
  retVal = e.message; //<-- this here shows the error
}
return retVal;
```

}
}

Did they change it recently or, what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use following

> retVal = e.toString() ;

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't display the message again.

Comment: The catch block execute if any error occurs. Please tell me that what is your purpose to write this code?

Comment: To display errors that might occur, e.g email alredy in use, password incorrect and so

Comment: Where are you using that email is used or not?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your try statement but in case your using one, do this instead;

```
} on FirbaseAuthException catch(e) {
retVal = e.message; //<-- this here shows the error
}
return retVal;
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/errors for more details

Comment: p/s: there is typo on 'FirbaseAuthException', suppose it is 'FirebaseAuthException'. Careful when you copy paste this answer guys. Anyway this answer is working for me. Thank you!